# Momentary on for one minute

Tags: switches, timer

I’ve built a dumb waiter using a 12 V electric over hydraulic pump and a cylinder. Currently using the wired remote to send it up and down. I would like to be able to push a button mounted to the wall and send it up and down without holding the button in. I plan on using a limit switch to stop it at the right spot. I would like to know the components necessary for the power to stay on till it hits the limit switch with just a push of the button.

Answer (score 4):

Generically you would use a self-hold relay and use the limit switch to break the circuit.

However, these things have been responsible for **maiming** and **deaths** and safety should be your first consideration. Having it operate semi-automatically adds additional safety considerations.

For example, [this](https://www.foxsports.com/stories/other/autopsy-waitress-caught-head-in-dumbwaiter) "fatal crushing injuries to her brainstem and cerebellum" and [this](https://ca.movies.yahoo.com/2014-12-06-brooke-baures-death-possibly-a-freak-accident-21003869.html) "To explain more of her specific location, orientation or obvious injuries would require an extremely graphic explanation" and I personally recall the unfortunate decapitation death of a waiter at a Toronto Chinese restaurant which I frequented some decades ago.

In my particular jurisdiction (Ontario, Canada) such devices are regulated under Ontario Reg. 209/01: ELEVATING DEVICES under Technical Standards and Safety Act, 2000, S.O. 2000, c. 16 and such major alterations would have to be done by a qualified and registered contractor.